# Регулярное выражение . Выбрать оъекты из Dfm

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь регуляркой выдрать объекты определенного типа(`TADOStoredProc`) из DFM.

```
object Form
    object obj1 :   TADOStoredProc
        object  obj1_1: Field
        end
        object  obj1_2: Field
        end
    end

    object  obj2: TADOStoredProc
        object  obj2_1: Field
        end
        object  obj2_2: Field
        end
    end

    object  obj3: TADOStoredProc
    end
end
```

вот мое выражение

```
(object\s*\S*\s*:\s*TADOStoredProc(.|\n)*)
```

которое захватывает от первого до последнего . но это не правильно . надо чтобы в совпадения был полностью объект со своим содержимым `obj1`, `obj2` и т.д.

Comment: Никогда не используйте `(.|\n)*`, заменяйте на `(?s)` + `.*` или, по крайней мере `[\s\S]*`. Это тут не сработает. Нужно что-то вроде [`(?m)^\s*object\s*\S*\s*:\s*TADOStoredProc[\s\S]*?^\s{4}end\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/19LJpx/1)

Comment: Это выражение выдерает до первого end, а надо чтоб со всеми вложенными объектами

Comment: У меня 3 совпадения, А вы что ожидаете?

Comment: [`TADOStoredProc\s+((object((?>.+?\s|(?2))*))|)end`](https://regex101.com/r/Y3t9go/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ну у вас ориентация на 4 пробельных символа перед end. пробелов может быть любое количество

Comment: @gregor Как вы собираетесь определить *границы* блока? Какой библиотекой регулярных выражений вы пользуетесь? Пока вы не определитесь с этим, невозможно дать однозначный ответ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ну вот теперь уже понимаю что никак. придется мудрить что то в коде пропуская вложенные объекты добираясь до закрывающего end

Comment: Есть два варианта решения: первый вариант- это привязаться к количеству пробелов. Не обязательно 4, главное- чтобы начало и конец записи были на одном уровне. Такой вариант реализуем почти во всех ЯП. Второй вариант- использовать рекурсию. Она присутствует не во всех ЯП в реализации регулярных выражений.

Comment: [Вот так без рекурсии можно обойтись](https://regex101.com/r/19LJpx/2), если кол-во пробелов для каждого уровня должно быть одинаковым.